# Is it possible to restrict routes based on traffic_calming tags?

Tags: openstreetmap, osrm

I'm new to OSRM and doing some research. As per the title, is it possible to restrict routing based on traffic_calming tags? For instance, could you add "traffic_calming" somewhere in "profiles/car.lua" or in "features/car/barrier.feature" such that when the routing was done it avoided some/all of roads with traffic calming on them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can mark `traffic_calming` as barrier by adding some code [here](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/master/profiles/car.lua#L341):

`result.barrier = node:get_value_by_key("traffic_calming") == "yes"`